# APIM to Front door ClientConnectionFailure errors

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-front-door

I'm seeing intermittent timeout for my requests from APIM to AFD with 'ClientConnectionFailure'

My architecture:
Architecture:
Customer --> APIM --> AFD --> Bkend Fn Apps

The requests from my APIM to AFD time out with 'ClientConnectionFailure'
The timeout happens due to underlying HTTP protocol closing the connection after default of 100 seconds

Since AFD logs are limited, is there a way to debug where exactly these intermittent failures happen?
Do they happen in AFD or in the backend infra and just show up at AFD level in AppInsights

Answer (score 0):

This issue may cause the client disconnects from the APIM gateway ***before obtaining a response or a full response***, which is the cause of the client connection failure.

Usually, The APIM gateway requires a long time to respond due to the high demand on the gateway, the back-end APIM instance points is not able to handle the volume of requests forwarded by the APIM gateway its slow on performance which leads the client to time out when awaiting a response or sometimes while still sending the request.

I have understood that you are experiencing a timed-out issue mostly appears on backend through APIM try calling your backend directly from your client by bypassing the APIM

[image]

The forward request policy has a default timeout set to 5 minutes, which indicates that APIM will break the connection if the connection remains inactive with the backend for longer than 5 minutes. The underlying network infrastructure can remove idle connections after 240 seconds, therefore values greater than 240 seconds may not be recognized. You can override this value as described here.

> **The ***forward-request*** refers  the client dropped the connection while the APIM gateway was sending the request to the back end or waiting for a response from the back end**

To more in detail ***refer*** this link:

[Azure API Management policy reference | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policies#advanced-policies)

[ClientConnectionFailure at forward-request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64705819/)